# Assembly thinks its location is in the TestResult folder

Tags: c#, mstest, visual-studio-2019

I'm debugging some old tests that are suddenly breaking for no obvious reason. The cause of the problem seems to be that one of the assemblies doesn't seem to know it's own location. The following code :

`string loc = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().Location;`

Returns the following destination

> \src\TestResults\Deploy_C62517A 2020-02-27 17_56_08\Out\MyDllName.dll

But what it should return is :

> src\DataAccess\bin\Debug\MyDllName.dll

This only happens on VS2019.On VS2017 it works properly(looks for the assembly where it should) and everything goes as normal. Any idea on what could cause this ?

The nuget packages that are used are : MsTest.TestAdapter 1.4.0 and MSTest.TestFramework 1.4.0

Comment: See the remarks in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getcallingassembly?view=netframework-4.8.

Comment: @H.G.Sandhagen but it seems it is the correct assembly name, only the location differs, so it doesn't seem to be an inlining or tail call problem.

Comment: Ok, sorry, my fault. The returned location contains the expected assembly name. I don't know very much about MSTest, but does the assembly exists at the given location (\src\TestResults\Deploy_C62517A 2020-02-27 17_56_08\Out\MyDllName.dll). If yes, then it is also loaded from there. Maybe the mechamism to load referenced assemblies was changed in VS2019.

Comment: @H.G.Sandhagen it does exist there. If the mechanism did change is there a way to revert it?